# Start flask webserver from commandline

Tags: python, flask

I put together a small application in PyCharm on my dev machine, that I'd now like to test on my Raspberry Pi, where it's supposed to be running in the end. On my dev machine, everything works so far, settings in PyCharm for the project being:

- environment variables: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;FLASK_APP=__init__.py`
- content roots and source roots set to PYTHONPATH activated

The folder structure looks like this:

```sh
├── __init__.py
├── controller
│   ├── AppLoopController.py
│   ├── DbController.py
│   ├── RfidController.py
├── model
│   ├── LogEntry.py
│   ├── Person.py
├── routes
│   └── routes.py
├── static
│   └── styles.css
├── templates
    ├── 404.html
    ├── base.html
    ├── index.html
    └── logs.html
```

My `__init__.py` looks like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from routes import routes

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.register_blueprint(routes.web)
```

I already did

```sh
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;FLASK_APP=__init__.py
```

cause that's what's seemed to be working in PyCharm, but trying to start by

```sh
/usr/local/bin/flask run
```

returns the following error:

```sh
Error: While importing "fzwk-app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/cli.py", line 236, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/opt/fzwk-app/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from routes import routes
ImportError: No module named 'routes'
```

I think I do understand what's wrong -- my educated guess is, that flask is not aware of the file structure (see error below). I just don't know what to do on the RPi's shell...

Comment: I would create `app.py` instead of `__init__.py` and run it with `python app.py`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion -- doesn't help me though cause as far as I understand, in order to start flask, I have to use the commandline tool flask which is then supposed to start the server and the python scripts.

Comment: you can put `app.run()` in `__init__.py` and run it with `python __init__.py` . Your could get your error if you run `__init__.py` from different folder using full path to `__init__.py` because then there is no folder `router` in different folder.

Comment: you could check `echo $PYTHONPATH` to see if you have your folder on the list.

Comment: That's it: didn't have my project in PYTHONPATH. Will answer my own question with that info asap, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had not set `PYTHONPATH` for my project to run properly.
So after setting it with

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project
```

it's running now when I call `flask run`.

Thanks for the input, furas!